# Record structure does not contain field alternate_group

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

Magento **data migration tool** gives the error after running this command.

Afate runing `php bin/magento migrate:data -r -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml`

> Error:  Record structure does not contain field alternate_group

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a custom field added by a third party extension.

So, you would need to add it to ignore in
/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource//map.xml.dist

in your case

/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/map.xml.dist

add this line in field_rules

    table_name.field_name

in your case

    table_name.alternate_group

Replace the table_name with the name of the table where the field is present.
You can get the table name by looking the error thrown in the terminal.

[mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step][table: here_is_your_table_name]: migrating.

Note : You might need to delete the entire database and re-run the process.